# Forgetting to say Shabbat additions in a Yom Tov Amidah - how to make up?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shabbat, yom-tov, tashlumin

If someone forgot to add in the Shabbat additions to a Yom Tov davening, do they have to make it up by repeating?

If so, and if they did so at Shacharit and only remembered after Chatzot (midday), how can they make it up?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would be different from any other case of an incomplete amida that you make up later?

Comment: @magicker72 it is not a given that everything that is missed is me'akev and therefore must be repeated, there are so many factors and I would like to know if anyone knows a direct halacha or responsa that deals with my exact question, if anyone has one.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, if they do have repeat amidah, is there any reason to think that they would not do a tashlumin at mincha?

Comment: @שלום any particular commentary on that which deals with my question?

Comment: @JoelK not really

Comment: See Mishnah Berurah and SA Harav 487:3

Comment: @שלום thanks, between the two of them I got the entirety of my answer! I'll write it up bli neder later

Comment: The interesting question is if you said one shacharit forgetting shabbat and then go back but forget yom tov, @JoelK

Comment: @DoubleAA that's mentioned here https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/710525/rabbi-daniel-z-feldman/tashlumin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one is not yotze Amidah on Yom Tov that falls on Shabbat if one completely neglected to mention Shabbat.

Mishna Berura on S'A O'C 487:1:

> **מקדש ישראל והזמנים** - ואם אמר מקדש ישראל לבד לא יצא וכן בשבת אם לא אמר מקדש השבת ואמר מקדש ישראל ג"כ לא יצא אף שהזכיר באמצע התפלה של שבת
> כיון שלא חתם בשל שבת וכל זה בין בקידושא בין בצלותא:
>
> **"Who sanctifies Israel and Holidays" [in the beracha of Yom Tov, after *Baruch Atah*..]** - If one said just "Who sanctifies Israel", one
> has not fulfilled one's obligation. So too, on Shabbat, if one didn't
> say "Who sanctifies Shabbat" but only said "Who sanctifies Israel" one
> has also not fulfilled one's obligation, even though one did mention
> [shabbat] in the middle of one's tefilla, because one didn't seal the
> prayer with Shabbat. This is true of both kiddush and tefilla.

So it sounds like it is only an issue to forget mentioning shabbat in the part after *Baruch Atah*. This appears to be the case, and following a discussion in Shulchan Aruch HaRav which goes into a lot more detail, it seems like there are opinions that would consider one as having fulfilled his obligation if one forgot Shabbat but did remember Yom Tov, *so long as they remembered to mention Shabbat in the middle*.

Conclusion: It's clear from the wording of both the Mishna Berura and Shulchan Aruch HaRav that if one forgot to mention Shabbat at all during the tefilla, then one has not fulfilled one's obligation and would either need to repeat or do tashlumin (follow citations for the exact laws of this), but if one did remember at least to say it in the beracha itself after "*Baruch Atah*..." but otherwise forgot to mention it in the middle, they do not have to make it up. If it's the other way around, one should seek one's LOR for whether one should follow the opinions brought in the SAH'R about whether they have fulfilled it or not.

Not answered yet:

- Is musaf any different due the korbanot being mentioned
- Is the procedure for tashlumin different from any other tashlumin?

Comment: If you already mentioned shabbat in musaf then you might no longer need to make up for forgetting it in shacharit. (Same with rosh chodesh etc.)